# What is the grub/machine include directory in GRUB source code?

Tags: bootloader, osdev, grub, grub2

I have always wondered how does GRUB 2 work. While reading it's source code, I saw that there are some #include directives which include seemingly nonexistent "grub/machine/...", for example in [grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S](https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/2.02-coreos/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S) bootloader file there is

```
#include <grub/machine/boot.h>
```

As it seems, it provides some architecture-specific macros, and my current guess is that it is created from sort of a mixin of files and macros from [include/grub](https://github.com/coreos/grub/tree/2.02-coreos/include/grub) when compiling for a specific architecture (e.g. `#include <grub/machine/boot.h>` might be directly copied from [include/grub/i386/pc/boot.h](https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/2.02-coreos/include/grub/i386/pc/boot.h), which I can assume by looking at macro references in boot.S and corresponding definitions in i386/pc/boot.h), but I am very unsure about my assumption as I have failed to find any documentation or article about that. Also I'm failing to understand, in case my assumptions are at least somewhat correct, why are some directories in [include/grub](https://github.com/coreos/grub/tree/2.02-coreos/include/grub) not just not similar to eachother (with, for example, having some files in common, like arm/ having it's own boot.h), but, in some cases, completely different, which seems counterintuitive from my perspective.

I would be glad to get some explanation on what is really going on behind those curtains as I'm trying to learn kernel development myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ./configure.ac, there is this line

```
      AC_CONFIG_LINKS([include/grub/machine:include/grub/$cpudir/$platform])
```

That line creates a symlink to the right CPU architecture `../../include/grub/i386/pc` after I ran `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make` on my machine. Inside of that directory will be the architecture dependent boot.h file.

I find it easier to understand repos like this running some of the build commands locally.

Comment: But what about folders which do not contain the boot.h file, for example, arm? Is the header still being inherited from somewhere?

Comment: It looks like `grub/machine/boot.h` is used only in architecture specific files. For arm, it relies on `uboot.h`. It looks like `boot.h` is used for multiple architectures, and `uboot.h` is used for others.